# JBoss Marshall options are not showing

Tags: jboss, marshalling, unmarshalling, jbossfuse, jboss-developer-studio

I am new to JBoss Fuse. I am trying to follow the tutorials and use Marshall and Unmarshall features using JBoss Developer Studio.

Problem, I am facing is, I am not able to see any options in Properties tab for Marshall.

This is what I am seeing on my IDE.

[Seen on my IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnz4S.png)

But in the tutorials, this what what is shown.

[Shown in tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6eek.png)

Please help me and let me know what needs to be done to see those options.

Thanks for your help.

Regards, Vishu

Comment: Look at Aurélien's reply, but however you can already try it fixed: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/neon/integration/updates/integration-stack/fuse-tooling/9.2.0.CI/. The instruction of how to install it is also provided in the link. The build from the link might not be stable enough though, so you might expect some issues there, but issue must have been fixed there already.

Answer (score 1):

you unfortunately hit a known regression in 9.1.0, see https://issues.jboss.org/browse/FUSETOOLS-2314

The good part is that this issue has been already fixed and fix will be available in next release, Fuse Tooling 9.2.0 which is currently planned at end of May.

regards,